# How to map server response retrieved in jsp to an iFrame

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, iframe, response

I'm using struts2 framework(java/js/html/css combo) for my webapp. I am reading a text file from server and I want to write the response to an iFrame present in the same jsp.

Flow:
(1) On click of a link, I pass the relative URL of the text file to jsp.
(2) When the jsp page loads, the java code in the jsp reads the file from server.
(3) Now this response has to be written to an iFrame present in the same jsp file

Can anyone plz help me in writing such response to an iFrame?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: right, so you are basically trying to display a external file with unknown file type(pdf,excel,word,txt e.t.c.) on to your webpage's iframe while retaining all of its formatting? This sound incrediblely complex. From your first comment, do you mean you can successfully convert all those different file into excel?

Comment: I couldn't write a jsp there. Pasted my code in JavaScript section. Feeling embarrassed lol. http://jsfiddle.net/Chande07/ZcPMB/

Comment: right, I think I know what you want but I am curious about 1 last thing, you concept is to let user to help determine the correct format to save those data into an excel. However you question heres is basically asking for a way to "determine the format of the incoming file, so that I can display it on webpage, and then user can help determine the format(again?)". Also, how does the final product looks like after your conversion? Can you gives us 1 or 2 short example? The first thing I think of to handle the whole thing is by using regular expression.

Comment: Originally I thought of using iFrame and then posted a question for alternate options. Did u see that jsp I posted in jsFiddle? I'd be happy if I can display the response content to iFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[code not tested, only a demostration of the concept]

here's some very rough idea as to how to fix your code, they definitly not the best but they should be enough to help you understand the concept.
However I'd still recommend going over the whole concept and maybe come up with a more efficent way to do what you need.

if you insist on using iframe, you need to make use of 2 seperate jsp as W3C says in "[Implementing HTML Frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331)":

> Any frame that attempts to assign as its SRC a URL used by any of its ancestors is treated as if it has no SRC URL at all (basically a blank frame).

so you'll need 2 jsp, the first one is basically what you have but the the src of the iframe changed to:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" width="80%" height="200" src="second.jsp?content=<%=all%>" name="imgbox" id="imgbox">
```

and the second one will be something like :

```
<html><body><%= request.getAttribute("content") %></body></html>
```

From the code you've shown you forced a "content update" on the iframe by using javascript. The proper/usual way to update an iframe is to provide different input parameter to the second jsp and let it update it for you.

Finally, I'd recommend using JSTL as much as possible instead of scriptlets. It is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the `src` attribute of the `IFRAME` to the jsp url when your link is clicked. Another way to do it is doing something like this:

```
<iframe src="" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<p><a href="yourJSPUrl" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

with the correct parameters of course

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the iFrame is already in the jsp. What I'm trying is to write the response from the server retrieved in the jsp's java code to the iFrame in the same jsp

Comment: In your javascript you can do something like:`var jspUrl = something + filePath; document.getElementById('yourFrameId').src = jspUrl;`

Comment: You are trying to display the jsp in iFrame. I want the server response, which is actually a text file/stream, to be written to the jsp's iFrame. This is my source question stackoverflow.com/q/23464296/3602818. Please look into it. Maybe u will get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: The server gives you a response to an URL right? Let's say it is `http://localhost:8080/MyFileServlet?file_name=someFile.txt`. This url has to be the src of the iframe. When the page is loaded, the iframe grabs the response from that url and drops it into its DOM. You may want to change the content type of the servlet or jsp to be "text/html" to prevent the user from downloading the file

Comment: Long story short you don't write the response to an IFRAME, you set the source of that IFRAME to the url that gives you the desired response